# Cleaning local git branches after squash-and-merge

Tags: git

I dislike squash and merge very much as I think that developers should be responsible to squash changes locally as needed and only commit small, easy to grasp, commits. Which can be part of a larger feature branch.

it also had the benefit that after I pulled the new master HEAD it was a breeze to clean all the local branches that were merged with:

```
[alias]
; cm = clean merged
cm = "!git branch --merged | grep -v '*' | xargs -n 1 git branch -d"
```

But the project i am working currently thinks that it is OK for developers to not care about their commits being meaningful. They enabled squash-and-merge by default on all github.com repositories.

Is there any way to at least keep the previous ease of cleanup from before? Is there any way to identify local branches were merged based on a squashed-merge?